# Keep ESP32 non-RTC GPIO pin state HIGH in deep sleep

Tags: esp32, arduino-ide

I'm using Arduino IDE, and I'm trying to keep a pin's state held (HIGH, in my case).

I have GPIO16, GPIO17, GPIO18 (which I believe are all **non-RTC GPIO** pins). They're connected to three P-channel MOSFETs, which power an RGB LED. So my three pins need to be held HIGH while sleeping.

When my ESP32 goes into deep sleep, the RGB LED slowly fades up to full white brightness

After searching around, the method posted elsewhere doesn't work as expected. I've tried the below, but no luck.

Arduino IDE:

```
gpio_hold_en((gpio_num_t) 16);
gpio_hold_en((gpio_num_t) 17);
gpio_hold_en((gpio_num_t) 18);
gpio_deep_sleep_hold_en();
delay(10000);
esp_deep_sleep_start();
```

Strangely though, now the blue LED (on GPIO 18) doesn't come on, just the other two (16 and 17) snap to full brightness as soon as I call deep sleep.

Does it matter that they're GPIO vs RTC GPIO?

Is it possible to hold them HIGH during deep sleep? I've also tried INPUT_PULLUP but no luck either.

They're SMD soldered on custom PCBs so I'm trying to solve this in software, before I consider swapping for N-Channel MOSFETs or just making new boards entirely.

Comment: If you always want them high in deep sleep, you could solder on pullup resistor. Adding as comment, as it really doesn't specifically answer your question.

Comment: Thanks EdHayes3. That's a good suggestion.